# More rows or more tables in a db design?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer, but would like some confirmation...

We received 220 text files of providers. Each file is a different category of provider. In total there are 3.2 million records.

My inclination is to create a category table and a provider table that links to category by an ID, then index any other columns that may be searched on like state, or even last name.

The other option is to have one table per category, but I think other than the smaller row size there are a lot of disadvantages to this approach.

It's a PHP/MySQL implementation.

Anyone think the separate table option is better for any reason?

Thanks,
D.

Comment: How will you be using the data? Will it eventually be aggregated or will there be an individual report for each provider?

Comment: Aggregated I believe... I'm just getting into the project, but I think it will just be SELECTed against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with two table approach -- `categories` and `providers`.

This will enable you to

1. easily adding new categories
2. easily reverse search Categories based on a column such as `state` of `provider`.

It make sense from data-structure point of view as well. One type of data in one table.

Comment: That's been my thought on this as well. Just wanted to throw it out to the community for feedback in case there was a case I hadn't thought of. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your original thought, and with Nishant's answer. In addition to his points, it also normalizes the data, and allows easy updates if a category changes names for some reason.